# Firebase rules - secure user data

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I cant't find any topic about secure user data with firebase rules.
I'm programming an app with ionic-angular and firebase (auth + database).

My structure in database is:

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0bEX.png)

---

What I want to achieve is, that every **authenticated user** can only see his **own** contacts.

---

At first i tried something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyIKM.png). But the permission had been denied.

So i had to read the firebase api again and again.
My next idea was [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHjLM.png). And it's working. I tested it, every user only has access to his own contacts, can add new ones, delete them, update them etc. **It's just about the firebase rules**.

---

My question is now, is my user data secured enough with the the second idea? I know that **".write & .read = true"** gives the whole world access to data, but they first had to be authenticated and the authenticated user must have the matching uid. Am i right or is there a problem?

Comment: Your first idea should have worked, although the rules are redundant (Notmfb's version is cleaner). Your second idea (with read/write to true) allows any user to read and write the contacts of any other user

Comment: Yes Notmfb was right. I had a code review again and looked up where the error is coming from and found my mistake in unsubscribing my subscription. The unsubscribe function was triggered too early. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a mockup? Assuming you are using the uid as the key value this should work:

```
 "rules": {
    "profiles": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid,
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid',
      },
```

I'm assuming under profiles you have the actual user id instead of 'user1,' 'user2', etc. And if you only want them accessing (not changing) change write to false.

Comment: yes it's a mockup and i have the actual userID instead. I'm getting this error with your rules: Error: permission_denied at /profiles/f9tPralCdWZSJ61BxaZ9DVNffAy1/contacts: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.. with my rules ("contacts:" {.write: true, .read: true} inside the $uid - it is working fine, but is my data secured with this rules?

Comment: Do you have any other rules under contacts? If you just say true it is not secure. You need to figure this out.

Comment: No i ain't got any other rules. I've uploaded a screenshot of my working rules. I will have a look again. Thanks